# How to speed up accessing a class list from Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to speed up my Python code when working with Selenium. Currently I'm using the `find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath)` function which returns me a `<class 'list'>`. As I am interested in the text of each of the elements in the list, I am extracting the text with `element.text`.

The weird thing is that this operation takes 0.02s to perform on average for each element in the list (which is why I create the `element_text` variable in the code to save at least on of the costly operations). The number of elements in the resulting `<class 'list'>` can easily exceed 5,000 elements which than consumes a lot of time aka this is my bottleneck.

Here is my problematic code snippet:

```py
    list_on_page = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "xpath") # <<< takes ~0.15s for 1000 elements on page

    for element in list_on_page:
      element_text = element.text    # <<< this takes 0.02s per element
      if element_text not in my_dict:          # next two lines take \
        my_dict.update({element_text : False}) # 5.2e-6s to complete if list has 1000 elements
```

I already tried to create a list of the texts and than iterate over this list, but this did not help, as the expensive operation is the `.text`-operation per element.

1. How can I speed this up?
2. Can I get the text right away from Selenium so I get a list of texts rather than a class list?

Comment: what you get from find_elements is a list of WebElements.  That's a type/interface that contains various methods along with a sort of pointer to an element in the DOM.  The text() method is going to extract what you need from the DOM node via the browser.  It's pretty fast, but you could also try something like Beautiful Soup which can parse from the raw markup to see if it's any faster.  (Or get the page source and create your own parsing routine...)

Comment: Another option to consider if speed is important would be using HTMLUnit as the webdriver.  It's much much faster than using a full-blown browser/driver pair.

Comment: @pcalkins thanks for your comments. When I debug my Python Code, I can clearly see, that the information in the `< class list>` already is in each object in the list. So I don't think, that, by the time I call `element.text` it is executing the DOM search. IMO this is done, when Selenium action `find_elements(...)` is executed. I would bag this also, as the time for the Selenium call increases as the number of elements on the page increase. HTMLUnit makes things more complicated IMO as I would ne a java server running, which, right now, I don't want.

Comment: that's interesting, I always figured it was a sort of pointer, but it will go to the dom again when text() method is called.  It's the only way they can tell if the element has gone stale.

Comment: The command sent to the browser from the webdriver would be /session/{session id}/element/{element id}/text ... that's sent via wire protocol methinks... then the browser returns the value.  So there's also that overhead of localhost to browser and back again.  If you get the page_source and parse that instead (outside of Selenium) it should be faster... and I think Selenium will return the current page source (post JS updates... current state of DOM)